# Stop 2D platformer character from sliding down slope

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, platformer, character-controller

I'm making a 2D platformer game with the default Unity 2D physics. I am implementing slopes, but my player slips down the slope because of the physics.

[image: Character standing on slope]

Here is the code I use for the player movement:

```
MoveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
rbd2.velocity = new Vector2(MoveInput * speed, rbd2.velocity.y);
//rotacion de personaje
if (MoveInput > 0)
{
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);            

}
if (MoveInput < 0)
{
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);            

}
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsMaterial2D.html

Comment: is your code that you shared within Update() function?

Answer (score 0):

Unity here is constantly running physics simulation (trying to mimic the actual world a bit) and thus applies various forces to your rigidbody2d depending on situation. If rigidbody is on the slope there is the *downwards force* of gravity applied to it. It results in downwards and backwards velocity so that object starts to slide back.

**So your problem is** - that this backwards/downwards velocity is greater than your forward/upward velocity which you applied.

We can not change physics algorithm, however we can adjust the **parameters**.

to fix it (and make it behave the way you want) adjust these parameters:

- adjust Mass in Rigidbody2d. Try to *increase* it. This alone ***should*** solve the problem.
- you can lower the slope angle
- apply higher velocity

It should work..  Also take a look at [Rigidbody2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody2D.html) and play around with its parameters until it behaves as you want.